# Access DBContext in ASP.NET Core 6 from data access layer class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, data-access-layer, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app that I created from a VS 2022 template. I'm writing a custom data access layer and business logic layer.

I know I can pass the `_context` from the controllers down through the BLL in the DAL, however I would prefer to have direct access from the DAL. I don't see any reason the BLL or the web code need to have anything to do with data access.

I've tried several examples of injection, but I can't seem to get any of them to work. Does anyone have a good solution?

**Edit:**

In Project.cs I have added DbContext:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I would like to get access to DbContext in my custom data access layer without having to pass DbContext all the way down from a Controller into my DAL contructor like so:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Code
  public class CustomDataAccessLayer
  {
    public string[] GetCustomers()
    {
      DbConnection conn = DbContext.GetConnection();
      //Whatever query logic I want to do here
```

Is there any way to access DbConext directly without having to pass it in from within a controller action?

Comment: could you show us your code?

Comment: 1) register your objects. 2) inject them in the classes. Please show what you have tried.

Comment: What's the problem you have met? You can't inject `dbCOntext` into DAL?  You need to provide more details.

Comment: Added to original question for clarity.

Comment: My ultimate goal is really to just get access to the DbContext connection so that in my custom DAL I can create a SqlConnection and execute whatever SQL I would like to against the database without regard to the separate entities. If there's another way to get the connection from my DAL without having to pass it down from the controller I'd be fine with that.

Comment: I don't think you can access `Dbcontext` directly in the class.

Comment: I believe you are correct Xinran. I gave up on that pursuit and just used DI passed down from my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) you can read about how DI works exactly.

I'll provide some example of how you're supposed to do that.

first you need to have `DataContext` Class that extends `DbContext` Class that will be like this

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyProject.Context
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the `Program.cs` you need to add the`DataContext`like this

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
        .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")); // for example if you're holding the connection string in the appsettings.json
});
```

and then in the Logic class that you want to use it in make a data member in the class of type `DataContext`

```
private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
```

and your constructor must take `DataContext` as parameter and Initialize your constructor will look like this

```
public ClassName(DataContext dataContext)
{
    _dataContext = dataContext;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what the ASP.Net Core project template already gave me. I'm looking to access the DbContext directly from within my custom data access layer without having to pass it from the controller in through the DAL constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**with json** :

```
var constr = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"];
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => {
    opt.UseSqlServer(constr);
});
```

Json :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=Victus;Database=TeamDb;Trusted_Connection=true;"
}
```

AppDbContext.cs :

```
public class AppDbContext:DbContext {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions <AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<team> teams { get; set; }
}
```

Home Controller :

```
private AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    public HomeController(AppDbContext appDbContext) {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View(_appDbContext.teams);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add dbcontext to a controller, nobody does it if there is a data access layer, DI will automatically inject the context

```
 public class CustomDataAccessLayer
 {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
   
        public CustomDataAccessLayer(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

         public string[] GetCustomers()
        {
           //your code
        }
    
 }
```

Comment: How do I inject `CustomDataAccessLayer` in the services, at `Program.cs`?

Comment: @carloswm85 Your question is not clear. pls post the code you have tried and mark the place you want to use CustomDataAccesLayer

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad question. I was asking about `CustomDataAccessLayer` as it were a service. I assume the code you shared should follow a similar logic. I figured it out for my case. The correct code for adding the service was adding in `Progam.cs` this line: `builder.Services.AddScoped<IOperationsService, OperationsService>();` In a ASP.NET Core 6 project. My question was about that line.